# is it safe to send SSL-pubkey to users via network without encrypted?

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, websocket

Just consider the following issue:

**1) Firstly, a client User connects to a remote WebSocket Server based on "ws://" protocol instread of "wss://" protocol.**

**2) Once their websocket connection is established, remote WebSocket Server send the SSL-pubkey to that user using this (ws://..) websocket channel.**

**3) Then, client will delivers the SSL-pubkey via "ws.onmessage" event.**

**4) From them on, client will start sending encripted message using this pubkey to remote websocket server, and the server will decript those messages using its private key.**

I think step 3 and 4 are safe of course, but no sure about whether step 2 is safe or not.

So is it (step 2) possible to be hacked by someone?

Comment: I'm no security expert but I believe the public key can be shared any way you want. That's why it's called the public key. The private key is the one you need to keep safe and never send to anyone, encrypted or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;TR:  Wrong focus of the question. Use established crypto instead of trying to invent your own and failing.

> is it safe to send SSL-pubkey to users via network without encrypted?

A public key itself is public information, i.e. no information which needs to be specifically protected. And it is sent in clear as part of the certificate inside the TLS handshake (https://, wss://).

**But what you are trying to do with the public key is  a very bad idea.**

In your setup the client trusts any kind of public key which it gets because there is no method to verify who the key belongs to. A man in the middle attacker could simply replace this public key with his own key and this way the **client would trust the attacker**.

I recommend to abandon your idea and use proper wss:// with a certificate the client can trust (i.e. signed by a trusted CA). This does not cause any more overhead than your idea but is way more secure and can not be broken with a simple man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

The public key is public, **but** using ws means that someone can inject his own public key and thus, read the answer.

Why not simply using wss ? (on an https webpage, for the same obvious reason)

wss (as https) give confidentiality, but authentication too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for step (2) to be hacked by *anyone*. Contrast TLS, where the server sends a *certificate*, not just a public key, and which (a) is signed so as to authenticate the identity expressed by the certificate, so you know who it is supposed to be, and (b) is accompanied by a digital signature, which authenticates that the server owns that public key.

Using asymmetric encryption is also very poorly performing.

Don't do this. Use TLS. It already exists, already works, and is already secure.

Answer (score 0):

> is it safe to send SSL-pubkey to users via network without encrypted?

The answer varies from "maybe, it depends" to "no, its not". We would need to hear more about the protocol, the risk model and the threat model.

The "no, its not" is an easy one. Imagine a case of a political dissident connecting to a service to help his/her cause. Even the public key on the wire poses a threat. The risk model would include imprisonment, torture and death.

The "maybe, it depends" is harder to answer. As others have pointed out its usually accepted. But as Steffen points out, the protocol you describe is effectively an anonymous key exchange because there are no steps to establish provenance of the key. That is, an attacker could have swapped in his/her key for the real key. The risk model in this case is usually financial loss, which means its either (1) the consumer suffers or (2) the share holders suffers.

The second one is a tricky problem. Its known as the ["key distribution" problem](http://www.google.com/search?q="key+distribution"+problem). Its a [wicked hard problem *without* a solution](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

---

> So is it (step 2) possible to be hacked by someone?

As the protocol is described, yes, its very easy.